# Post request from Scheduled Job is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, scheduled-tasks

(I am new to JS, node.js and Heroku so I hope the question is clear) 
I have an Heroku node.js app, I was able to set up Heroku scheduler to run a task every 1 hour.

The task runs on time and the method `fireHook()` is called (I can see the log in the console) but the request does not work (I don't get any lo or error).

This is the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var request = require('request')


function fireHook(){
 console.log("firing")
 request({
    url: 'https://XXXXXX.herokuapp.com/jobs',
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    json: {"user_id":{ "id":"ddddd"}}

}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response)
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
    } else if (response.body.error) {
        console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
    } else {
        console.log('success: ', body)
        reportToSnitch()
    }
})
} 
fireHook();
process.exit();
```

2 questions:

1. Why sold the request not working ?
2. I am currently using a webhook to call my main app, is there a better way to call a function on the main app from the script directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your `process.exit()` is killing your script before the request has received its response. Try to move it into the callback:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var request = require('request')


function fireHook(){
 console.log("firing")
 request({
    url: 'https://XXXXXX.herokuapp.com/jobs',
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    json: {"user_id":{ "id":"ddddd"}}

}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response)
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
    } else if (response.body.error) {
        console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
    } else {
        console.log('success: ', body)
        reportToSnitch()
    }
    process.exit();
})
} 
fireHook();
```

JavaScript is asynchronous so you have to be careful to consider where and when certain events will occur. If your `reportToSnitch()` function is async as well, you may need to fire the `process.exit()` at the end of that function.